# use a variable to solve R.raw.background

Tags: android, r.java-file

I want to use

```
imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.raw.background);
```

as:

```
String imageSel= "background"
imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.raw.imageSel);
```

how can I use this using `imageSel` variable? please let me know

Answer (score 2):

how can I use this using imageSel variable?

Use `getIdentifier` to get resource id using resource name :

```
int rawId = getResources().getIdentifier(background, "raw", getPackageName());
imageView1.setBackgroundResource(rawId);
```

Comment: Thanks yar. But I am fetching some problem. Somehow it's not working in my code. Here, 
raw is the folder where i kept my pictures and background in my picture name.

Comment: @SiamAaron: i have one question why you have added images in `raw` folder because for images `drawable`,`drawable-mdpi`,.. folder is available ?

Comment: At first i was creating that apps by watching a tutorial. That's why its in raw folder

Comment: @SiamAaron: move images in `drawable` folder and then use  "drawable" instead of "raw"

Comment: Thanks yar!!! It worked!!! I screwed up with button and image button. Thanks alot. By the way it worked properly with Raw folder :)

Comment: @SiamAaron: Good if it's working with `raw` folder. it's better to use `drawable` folders by which you application cover more then devices using different size images

Comment: ok!!! I will do it!!! Thanks a lot!!!